# Blender bezier curve extrude not working correctly

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I'm trying to make a road model. but when I turn up the `Extrude` of the curve the mesh looks wrong :[image]

I already tried making a profile instead of extruding the curve but I got same result.

.Blend :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your curve, then press CTRL-A -> Rotation (apply rotation).

Then TAB -> edit mode, A (select all), N (open sidepanel) and enter 90 in Tilt.